# Open API Generator assigns 200 status code to default responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I'm currently working with the OpenAPI Generator for my API project, and I've run into an unexpected issue. When I define a default response in my OpenAPI specification, the OpenAPI Generator seems to be automatically assigning a 200 status code to that default response, which is not the behavior I expect.

In my YAML specification, I've defined the default response without specifying a status code, focusing on providing a description for unexpected errors:

yaml
Copy code
responses:
default:
description: Unexpected error

However, despite not specifying a status code, the generated Swagger documentation shows a 200 status code for this default response, which is not accurate for an error response.

Has anyone else encountered this issue with the OpenAPI Generator? Is there a way to prevent the generator from automatically assigning a 200 status code to default responses? Any insights, workarounds, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've reviewed my other response definitions, validated the OpenAPI specification, and checked the OpenAPI Generator's configuration settings, but I'm still encountering this behavior.

Comment: See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5675